# Searching Menu template suggestion by regions in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, drupal-theming, drupal-8

I want to write a theme suggestion, which add template suggestions contains the region name.
For example in my 'header region' i want a template like this: menu--header.html.twig, or in my 'custom region' - menu--custom_region.html.twig.

I want if I have two menus in the same region, i want to templating with one template.

I tried it with the function THEMENAME_theme_suggestions_menu_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables){} in my THEMENAME.theme file, but I dont know how I could query the region, which is. In the block alter, i know the region, so I think if I could call the block, which contains the menu, i could know the region too.

I would like to do this in my .theme file.

Is there a solution?

Comment: I think this is imposibble.

In the THEMENAME_theme_suggestions_menu_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) hook, the $variables doesn't contains where the menu is. So we don't know which block contains it or which region the menu appears in.

Comment: Menus can be rendered multiple times. For example you can place a menu block into the Footer, on the Block layout page (Structure >> Block layout), and after that you can place the same menu block to the Header. So the same menu appears in two different regions, but in theme_suggestions hook, we don't know where is the actual menu.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I try to find an other way to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to achieve same thing but it doesn't need to be region name in suggestion. It could be block id and when you place block in header region you can change that block id.

Check this answer: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/219770/32059